# How to configure Payum so it can handle PayPal standard payments (not express checkout payments)?

Tags: php, symfony, paypal, payum

How to configure [Payum for Symfony](https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/docs/symfony/get-it-started.md) so it can handle PayPal standard payments (not express checkout payments); exactly same way a basic PayPal button would do?

The example provided in documentation is for Express Checkout only:

```
public function prepareAction()
{
    $gatewayName = 'paypal_express_checkout';

    $storage = $this->get('payum')->getStorage('FrontBundle\Entity\Payment');

    $payment = $storage->create();
    $payment->setNumber(uniqid());
    $payment->setCurrencyCode('CHF');
    $payment->setTotalAmount(100); // 1.00
    $payment->setDescription('A description');
    $payment->setClientId('anId');
    $payment->setClientEmail('foo@example.com');

    $storage->update($payment);

    $captureToken = $this->get('payum')->getTokenFactory()->createCaptureToken(
        $gatewayName,
        $payment,
        'done' // the route to redirect after capture
    );

    return $this->redirect($captureToken->getTargetUrl());
}

public function doneAction(Request $request)
{
    dump($request);
    $token = $this->get('payum')->getHttpRequestVerifier()->verify($request);

    $gateway = $this->get('payum')->getGateway($token->getGatewayName());

    // You can invalidate the token, so that the URL cannot be requested any more:
    // $this->get('payum')->getHttpRequestVerifier()->invalidate($token);

    // Once you have the token, you can get the payment entity from the storage directly.
    // $identity = $token->getDetails();
    // $payment = $this->get('payum')->getStorage($identity->getClass())->find($identity);

    // Or Payum can fetch the entity for you while executing a request (preferred).
    $gateway->execute($status = new GetHumanStatus($token));
    $payment = $status->getFirstModel();

    // UPDATE SUBSCRIPTION END DATE IN USER ENTITY

    $subscription_end_date = new \DateTime("now+ 365 day");
    $subscription_end_date_string = $subscription_end_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
    $user->setSubscriptionEndDate($subscription_end_date);
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush($user);

    return $this->render('FrontBundle:App:subscription_confirmation.html.twig', [
        'page_title' => 'Accompagnement, coaching de vie personnelle et professionnelle à Genève',
        'subscription_end_date' => $subscription_end_date_string,
    ]);

}
```

But my client wants his users are able to make payments without any PayPal account (PayPal Guest Checkout).

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok mine worked now, you just need to set up the Solutiontype

**Sole:** Buyer can check out without creating a PayPal account. This is referred to as PayPal Account Optional.

**Mark:** Buyer must have a PayPal account to check out.

```
$payment['SOLUTIONTYPE'] = 'Sole';
```

Check out here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/